# Access params value from a form tag to display a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

This is a very basic issue : I want to display the quantity value in my view, from a form_tag input, but I have the hash instead.

```
 <%= form_tag order_items_path do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'product_id', @product.id %>
    <%= number_field(:quantity, in: 1.0..20.0, step: 1) %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Add to cart', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
```

order_items controller

def create

```
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

if current_user.orders.find_by(state: 'pending')
  OrderItem.create!(product: @product, quantity: (params[:quantity]), order: current_user.orders.find_by(state: 'pending'))
else
  order = Order.create!(user: current_user, state: 'pending')
  OrderItem.create!(product: @product,  quantity: (params[:quantity]), order: current_user.orders.find_by(state: 'pending'))
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_path }
  format.js
end
```

What I have when I try to display that in my orders view:

```
  <% @order.order_items.each do |item| %>
  <div id="order-item-id-<%=item.id%>">
    <div class="container mt-4 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" >
      <div>
        <%= item.product.name %>
        <%= item.quantity %>
      </div>
```

Is the hash from the form_tag:

Ethipia {"{:in=>1.0..20.0, :step=>1}"=>"1"}

I tried lots of solutions like quantity: (params[:quantity].value) but nothing works. Some help out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your mistook [`number_field`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/number_field) with [`number_field_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag). Just change

```
<%= number_field(:quantity, in: 1.0..20.0, step: 1) %>
```

to

```
<%= number_field_tag(:quantity, nil, in: 1.0..20.0, step: 1) %>
```

Note the `nil` that is the initial value of the field, you might want to use `1` or another number instead.

Comment: OMG number_field_tag is doing the job perfectly! Thank you so much ;)

Comment: sorry,I thought I 've done it but I must have clicked the wrong button ;)